# Running a process from jenkins

Tags: c#, powershell, batch-file, jenkins, process

My console application is responsible for starting a WCF service in interactive mode (ie. the service does not get installed as a Windows service in that case).
In order for my application to start the latter, the application invokes the compiled executable using the following method:

```
    static bool AutoStartService()
    {
         var MyProcessFile = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath($"pathToExecutable/MyServiceExe.exe");

         Process myProcess = new Process();
         myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = MyProcessFile;
         myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
         myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

         myProcess.Start();
         Thread.Sleep(WaitForTheServiceToStart); 
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Note that this approach works just fine when debugging from Visual Studio.
However, when the console application is invoked from Jenkins (note that I gave Jenkins admin access and it logs in as a normal user), then the service process does not seem to stick or be visible from the Console application. I can tell it at least starts and stops as I can see the logs being written to file.
The Console application is started using a batch command from Jenkins (I also tried using Powershell, but without luck).

Any suggestion on how to do that?
I have tried with both debug and release builds of my Console app C# project, but it makes no difference.

### EDIT

I have edited the following properties, but without success:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.Environment.Add("BUILD_ID", "dontKillMe");
```

I am now seeing the following warning, but I don't believe installing the service is the only way to go as this is what I am doing when running this code without Jenkins and it works. Maybe Jenkins does not allow it though?:

> Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger.  A Windows Service must first be installed (using installutil.exe) and then started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Services Administrative tool or the NET START command.

### EDIT2

I went a step further. The reason why I was getting the former message is that the service checks "Environment.UserInteractive" to either run as interactive or to start/run the installed service. For some reasons this flag is always set to false, while it should be true in my case.
Is there a way to fool the service to think that flag is true?

Comment: @zett42, not really. That is using a shell, which I am not using. Unless that allows to start .exe processes too. In which case, I am unsure how to do that.

Comment: As I understand this, the shell is not relevant. You only need to set environment variable `BUILD_ID=dontKillMe` when launching the service. `myProcess.StartInfo.Environment.Add("BUILD_ID", "dontKillMe");`. If this works, I'll turn it into an answer.

Comment: @zett42, no, it does not seem to work I'm afraid

Comment: Are you sure the process is still getting terminated by Jenkins (which shouldn't happen due to the environment variable) or does it actually terminate on its own, because of some error condition?

Comment: @zett42, no I am not sure Jenkins terminates it, but I added an exit condition in my script, requiring someone to hit 'q', which should never happen (and the service should then remain active forever, right?). Could it be that Jenkins is not allowing to run services this way - ie. as an invoked process? Please see my edit. Thanks